# WPF Binding IEnumerable to ListBox with a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to bind an IEnumerable class UserList to a ListBox in XAML, but I'm not able to resolve the name of the object. My xaml code is as follows:

```
            <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="UserListBox" Width="400"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource userList}}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserListTemplate}">

            </ListBox>
```

I have userList instantiated in MainWindow.xaml.cs as well, but I guess I'm not doing something right. Intention is to have ListBox read from UserList and create a list of Users from that IEnumerable. How do I fix this?

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataConnection.CreateAndOpenDB();
        src.UserList userList = new src.UserList();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local variable can not be resolved by the StaticResource extension.

Create a UserList property like shown below, and set the Window's DataContext to `this`. If you want to be able to add or remove elements after setting the DataContext, the class UserList should implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. It may do so by deriving from `ObservableCollection`.

```
public src.UserList UserList { get; } = new src.UserList();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataConnection.CreateAndOpenDB();
    // add elements to UserList here

    DataContext = this;
}
```

Then write the Binding in XAML like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}"
```

---

See [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) for an introduction.